# How to get an image from a webservice on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services

How can I fetch an image through webservices on an iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

You can encode your image by base64, then embed the base64 string in webservice payload, when iPhone receive the message decode base64 string into NSData, then you will be able to display it.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:webPath]]];
```